# Is `eof`` a valid state of `ifstream`?

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

The code is:

```
ifstream fin("D://abc.txt", ios::in);
string line;
while ( fin ) {
    getline( fin, line );
    cout << line << endl;
}
```

The text file is:

```
hi, I am Eric!
hi, I am Jack!
```

And the output is

```
hi, I am Eric!
hi, I am Jack!
hi, I am Jack!
```

And when I change the condition to `!fin.eof()`, output is correct. **Is `eof` a valid state of `ifstream` ?**

Comment: Best way to read `while (std::getline(fin, line)) {}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `eof` state is only reached once you try reading **past** the end of the stream. The `getline` call that reads the last line from your file does not do so (it reads up until the newline). But the `getline` call in the next iteration of the loop will reach the end of the file.

A better way to read every line in the file is :

```
while (getline(fin, line)) {
    cout << line << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because the state is not changed until *after* the `std::getline` function fails. This means that you read the first two lines correctly, but then the state isn't changed so you enter the loop *again*, but now the `std::getline` call fails but you don't check for it, and it's also now that the `eof` flag is set.

You should do e.g.

```
while (std::getline(...))
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The usage

```
while(fin)
```

is not good. it will check the value of fin, not whether fin reaches the end.

you may check this page:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

when you finish the second call of function getline, the pointer fin not point to NULL, so you go into the third process in while, the third time you call

```
getline(fin,line);
```

it meet the eof of fin, so fin change state, then you won't go to the forth call, but since you didn't clear the value of

```
line
```

so it will also print

```
hi, I am Jack!
```